# Mule esb 3.8 how to add object variable (HashMap) into payload (HashMap)

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave, payload, mule-esb

Hello need a bit of help to understand how I can merge 2 payloads from db calls into one - final payload.

First payload is like:

```
[{Name=John, Age=31}]
```

Second payload is like:

```
Address=[{Planet=Earth, Continent=Europa, Town=London},{Planet=Earth, Continent=Europa, Town=Dublin}]
```

Final result I am expecting as such:

```
[{Name=John, Age=31, Address=[{Planet=Earth, Continent=Europa, Town=London},{Planet=Earth, Continent=Europa, Town=Dublin}]}]
```

I was try ++ and putAll but its not happy and don't allow me to do it, preferable without dw.
Technically I understand that its need to add but cant find right syntactic and help is not helpful for such :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your payload is an `ArrayList` of `HashMap`, not a `HashMap`. Similarly your `flowVars.Address` is also a `List`. For adding it in the first HashMap of your payload you can try the following

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[#[payload.get(0).put("Address", flowVars.Address)]]]></expression-component>
```

Comment: for some reasons getting null payload as result? {NullPayload}

Comment: You don't have to set it as payload. Just run it as MEL expression

Comment: yes but if flowVars.Address is array it throw me {NullPayload}, if its { } its fine, seems need a mix of add and put?

Comment: You mean the payload is becoming as NullPayload after you execute this expression, right?

Comment: You need to use expression component. It does not changes the payload. https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/expression-component-reference

Comment: yes expression or set-variable - but result is {NullPayload}

Comment: oh hold one, seems its not work in set-variable but in blank expression its working...

Comment: Just to clarify, the expression will update your payload, but will return null only. You just need to use `expression component` that does not change your payload with this null value, it just runs the MEL expression

Comment: yes thanks for help, i update you answer with exact syntacsis that was work for me, hope that help somebody as well as was bang my head on such for a day and cants solve it my self :)